# Is there a way to demand a chopper motorbike / is there a regular spawn point?

Tags: watch-dogs

I have sunk a few hours into Watch Dogs now and I am a big fan of the motorbikes. I am not a big user of the CoD (car on demand) app as you don't really have to go very far to find a good vehicle, but when I first laid my eyes on the seemingly rare chopper, I knew what I wanted to ride off into the sunset with. However, my happiness soon turned to disappointment when I found that the chopper was not an option on CoD.

To reiterate my question; is there a way in which I can maybe unlock the chopper motorbike for demand or is there one or several spawn points for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every vehicle you drive gets unlocked in the Car on Demand app for purchase after you have driven it once. So if you have already used the bike, it should be available for purchase there for 5000$. If you have not used it yet, here is where you can find it:

I have found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaV4mu0h6Fg), that shows a location where the bike spawns. Apparently, sometimes a dirtbike spawns instead of the chopper, so you might have to reload a few times until the chopper appears.

I have marked the location shown in the video on a map that I found on wiiware.in:

[image: Watch Dogs Map Chopper]

You can also unlock the chopper by playing a fixer contract, that requires you to race with it through the city, but I could not find out which of the fixer contracts is the right one. I will add the location if I find it out (or if someone else knows, feel free to share).

Comment: I think you can also unlock it by hacking a random pedestrian.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have indeed driven the chopper before but I don't recall it being available on demand, I will check later when I can. That map looks very helpful, I will be sure to use it if I cannot unlock the chooper by other means. Guess I better start doing fixer contracts :)

Comment: @5pike Yes, I wasn't sure about that, bacause I don't know if the cars you can unlock by hacking are from a predetermined list or if they can be any vehicle randomly. Simon M: Happy to help :)